# how to find number and remove it from varchar string in oracle sql

Tags: sql, plsql

I have following string

val = "Testabc123xyz32dfghj"

I need below output only caps character without number:

output : TESTABCXYZDFGHJ

Which sql strings functions to use?

Answer (score 1):

Technically you want this:

```
select upper(regexp_replace('Testabc123xyz32dfghj', '\d')) from dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @val varchar(max) = 'Testabc123xyz32dfghj'
declare @num1 as int 
set @num1=0

while @num1<10
begin
  set @val=REPLACE(@val,cast(@num1 as varchar),'')
  set @num1=@num1+1
end
print UPPER(@val)
```

Comment: This is not Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Use this function :-

```
regexp_replace('Testabc123xyz32dfghj', '[0-9]', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select upper(regexp_replace('Testabc123xyz32dfghj', '\d')) from dual;
```